# How to pass the images to library project from main project in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have one library project and one main project, I want pass the images from main project to my library project, So I can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the images to the library project.

While using the image in the code, instead of using

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"];
```

use as follows:

```
NSBundle *bundle = nil;

bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithIdentifier:@"com.test.libary"]; //library project's identifier

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [bundle pathForResource:@"img" ofType:@"png"]];
```